# Gazebo laser sensors not detecting objects with blender world model

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9, blender

I have made a new basement parking world model in blender before exporting it in different formats (dae, stl, obj ) destined for gazebo. The model is correctly imported in gazebo however, the sensors onboard my robot is not able to detect the pointclouds in 3D. The velodyne sensor in particular propagates circular concentric wavefronts as if the walls of the model are non existent (non visible) to it.

[image]
[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <model name="veolia_vxv">
    <static>true</static>
    <self_collide>false</self_collide>
    <link name="link">
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1.0 1.0 1.0</scale>
            <uri>model://veolia_vxv/meshes/veolia_2.stl</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>     
      </collision>

      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <scale>1.0 1.0 1.0</scale>
            <uri>model://veolia_vxv/meshes/veolia_2.stl</uri>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

N.B 1:The model in blender has also been exported to obj, and dae, but no extensions seems to be working.
N.B 2: Using the gazebo building editor, a different model works fine with my 3D sensors but the editor is very much limited in options for more elaborated models, the reason i switched to blender. The problem IMHO is coming either from blender or the model integration in ros/gazebo.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
The model should be placed in ~/.gazebo/models for it to be recognised by gazebo.

Comment: Glad you could fix it. Please mark your question as answered.

Comment: Can't find the "answered" tag :(

Comment: I think there should be a green tick next to your answer, isn't it?